# Not receiving input from all fields from PHP contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, contacts

This has been bugging me all day and I've given up trying to figure it out for myself, but the answer's probably really obvious...

My contact form works fine, however I don't receive input for all fields. I only get name, phone, email and message. I've given the form fields a name attribute so I'm not sure what's happening.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              
                               <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" name="name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone Number *" name="phone" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" name="email" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                
                                   <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="suburb" placeholder="Your Suburb *" id="suburb" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your address.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div> 
                                
                              <div class="select"> 
                               <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
        <select class="selectpicker" name="state" id="state" data-width="100%" data-height="100%" title="Choose State *" data-style="btn-primary">     
          <option>QLD</option>
          <option>NSW</option>
       </select>
    </div>    
          </div>
          </div>
                               
                               <div class="right-form-column">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Post Code *" name="postcode" id="postcode" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your post code.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                 </div>                                              
                               </div>
          </div>                                                                                           
         </div>
                            
                              <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="select"> 
                               <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
        <select class="selectpicker" name="product1" id="product1" data-width="100%" data-height="100%" data-live-search="true" title="Choose Product" data-style="btn-primary">
           <optgroup label="100 Series">      
                <option>90mm Grey Standard</option>
                 </optgroup> 
              </select>
         </div>    
           </div>
         </div>
                               
                               <div class="right-form-column">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity1" id="quantity1">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                 </div>                                              
                               </div>
    </div>        
                              
                            <div class="select">
                             <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
        <select class="selectpicker" name="product2" id="product2" data-width="100%" data-height="100%" data-live-search="true" title="Choose Product" data-style="btn-primary">
           <optgroup label="100 Series">      
                <option>90mm Grey Standard</option>
                 </optgroup> 
              </select>
        </div>    
          </div>
                                </div>
                               
                                 <div class="right-form-column">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity2" id="quantity2">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                 </div>                                              
                               </div>
    </div>     
                              
                             <div class="select">
                             <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
         <select class="selectpicker" name="product3" id="product3" data-width="100%" data-height="100%" data-live-search="true" title="Choose Product" data-style="btn-primary">
           <optgroup label="100 Series">      
                <option>90mm Grey Standard</option>
                 </optgroup> 
              </select>
        </div>    
          </div>
                                </div>
                               
                                 <div class="right-form-column">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity3" id="quantity3">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                 </div>                                              
                               </div>
    </div>     
                                          
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Additional comments" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                <div id="success"></div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl" name="submit">submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'myname@mydomain.com'; // PUT YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS HERE
$email_subject = "P Services Contact Form:  $name"; // EDIT THE EMAIL SUBJECT LINE HERE
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website's contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details: From: $name\n Phone: $phone\n E-Mail: $email_address\n Suburb: $suburb\n State: $state\n Post Code: $postcode\n Product: $product1\n Quantity: $quantity1\n Product: $product2\n Quantity: $quantity2\n Product: $product3\n Quantity: $quantity3\n Message:\n $message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)){ 
    echo "Mail sent successfully.";
} 
    else{ echo "Error.";
}        
?>
```

Comment: Please reduce that WALL OF CODE to a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: well, you just don't assign `$suburb = $_POST['suburb'];`, but you try to use it. Same for state, product, ..

Comment: At the top of your code do `die(var_dump($_POST))` and see what the post is receiving before you do anything

Comment: Lots of your variables like `$suburb` etc etc etc do not exist. They only exist as `$_POST['suburb']` etc etc etc A quick look at your PHP Error Log should have told you that !!!!!

Comment: use isset instead of empty, if the variables are not exist what empty will verify ? check what $_POST is has after post submit .

Comment: <option> tag should have attribute value. <option value="">

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Best you look at the manual page for `empty()`

Comment: on your from do this `<form method="POST" action="handleRequest.php">` or whatever page that you are posting your form data to, it works for me

Comment: @RiggsFolly what empty($_POST['name']) will give ? 'name' is undefined right ?

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius Look at `<form>' tag attribute defaults

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu From the manual `empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.`

Comment: Please change your method to *$_GET* or use *method='post'* while writing the form

Comment: @RiggsFolly  in phpfiddle.org it gives error undefined index and even I am using php 7 in my localhost it gives error undefined index .

Comment: @RiggsFolly check manual first example #1 . $var is either 0, empty, or not set at all . so when it is not set what it returns ?

Answer (score 1):

make sure that, you've removed *disabled* tag in html elemets.

THIS IS WRONG. PHP WON'T RECOGONIZE YOUR ELEMENT.

```
<input type="text" disabled>
```

INSTED OF USING *disabled* you can use *readonly*.
THIS IS THE CORRECT METHORD

```
<input type="text" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to change is specify the method of form submission (**POST** or **GET**).

**Either use**

`<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate method="POST">`

**OR**

Access the form variables using **$_GET** like `$_GET['name'])`

Comment: You cant use the `$_GET` superglobal if you set the form type to POST

Comment: Yes but It's another option. Not together I meant.

Comment: Thanks Rossi. Sorry for my ignorance but I'm still new to code, how would I access the form variables using $_GET?

Comment: Just replace $_POST with $_GET everywhere. That will do.

Comment: Thank you so much! Turns out I missed a $_POST in the javascript, which I didn't even think about.

Comment: OK. You didn't say there is Javascript involved.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns all the information for me

[image]

All i did was change the form method so all the data is being passed its just needs to be handled correctly in your PHP

Comment: Hi Kenziiee, what did you change the form method to?